# Iterating through a 3 dimensional array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a function that will merge a 3 dimensional array into a an array of object.

Example:

```
var input = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
       [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]];
```

Result:

```
[
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]
```

So what I did is iterate through each array and then get first element and last element and put it inside an object.

However I am stuck in two things:

1. It doesn't get all the items in the array using `myObj[employeeData[i][j][0]] =  employeeData[i][j][k];` only the 2nd
   array dimension.

Which is in this case this one:

```
[['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]];
```

2. If I push object into the empty array I'll get the following:

   [[object Object] {
     age: 36,
     firstName: "Mary",
     lastName: "Jenkins",
     role: "manager"
   }, [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object], [circular object Object]]

Not sure what circular Object means.

Here's my codes so far:

```
function arrayObject(data) {

  var arr = [];
  var myObj = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
      for(var k = 0; k < data[i][j].length; k++){
        myObj[data[i][j][0]] =  data[i][j][k]; 
        arr.push(myObj);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;

}

var input = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']],
            [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]];

var output = arrayObject(input);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made mistakes:

- First you don't need 3 loops, exactly two will do it,
- Second, myObj should be local to the upper loop, since its value will
  be changed for each array inside input.

> ```
> function arrayObject(data) {
>   var arr = [];
>   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
>       var myObj = {};
>           for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
>               myObj[data[i][j][0]] =  data[i][j][1]; 
>           }
>       arr.push(myObj);
>   }
>   return arr;
> }
>
> var input = [
>   [
>       ['firstName', 'Joe'], 
>       ['lastName', 'Blow'], 
>       ['age', 42], 
>       ['role', 'clerk']
>   ],
>   [
>       ['firstName', 'Mary'],
>       ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
>       ['age', 36],
>       ['role', 'manager']
>   ]
> ];
>
> var output = arrayObject(input);
> console.log(output);
> ```

Comment: Can you explain more why having the myObj at the very top only select the first set of array items? sorry trying to understand this. Dummy here.

Comment: yes sure! when setting  var myObj = {}, this means a new variable will be created after each loop, which means the old values will get dumped and not stuck in the array, If we keep myObj global, that means all the variable will be pushed there and in the return we will have more than 2 objects (in the example) since in every array we push again, hope it makes sense

Comment: is there a way you could provide a little bit visuals? like a code in JSFiddle explaining how it works? I appreciate time.

Comment: you can basically, just put the myObj declaration at top and see the console, u'll understand

Answer (score 0):

You could consider this:

```
var items = [[['firstName', 'Joe'], ['lastName', 'Blow'], ['age', 42], ['role', 'clerk']], [['firstName', 'Mary'], ['lastName', 'Jenkins'], ['age', 36], ['role', 'manager']]];

var result = [];
// first loop through items
items.forEach(function(item)
{
   var obj = {};
   // then loop through properties
   item.forEach(function (value)
   {
      // then set property and value
      obj[value[0]] = value[1];
   });

   // once all is done push the object
   result.push(obj);
});

console.log(result);
```

which result would have the desired format you wanted.

hope that helps